# Can the glTF format be used for 3D printing?

Tags: 3d-design

Can the glTF format be used for 3D printing?

If not, is there any tool can convert it to another format such as STL, OBJ, STEP, and IGES?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as can be found it should be possible to convert glTF into STL (or OBJ).

You could try to use an online converter to do this, e.g. [this one (greentoken)](http://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/); and [this (assimp)](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_features_formats.html) may be useful too.

According to [this](https://b2b.partcommunity.com/community/faq/view/211/95/105/0/how-to-convert-3d-models-between-file-formats-i-e-fbx-to-obj-o) greentoken supports glTF as input and STL as output, but it is reported by @Trish that that does not work. Assimp could output STL files which then could be used by slicer programs to generate the specific G-code file to print the model on your printer.

Comment: Greentoken does not accept GLTF, Assimp though does.

Answer (score 4):

No, `gltf` is not a format that slicers accept commonly, and indeed, it is not even intended to be reverseable in the 1.0 format version. This has changed a little for the 2.0 standard. Some programs that allow exporting into the sliceable `stl` and  `obj` formats can also import `gltf`:

- [blender](https://www.blender.org/) has an [importer plugin](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO) - more  info [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93415/how-to-open-a-glb-or-gltf-file-in-blender)
- [SketchUpp](https://www.sketchup.com/) has an [importer plugin](https://www.simlab-soft.com/3d-plugins/GLTF_Importer_For_Sketchup-main.aspx)

You have to be careful though: formats like `dae` or `stl` are meant to transfer 3d objects usually without the loss of information or with just a minimal loss (stl, for example, does technically not contain a *scale* natively), while `gltf` is end users and [does not contain all the information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549453/is-there-a-way-to-convert-gltf-to-dae). This can lead to models getting distorted and destroyed on importing them into a rendering or modeling software.